Android 15. Edge to edge mode hide a top View
I have a Pixel 6 device and updated today Android version to 15.
I test a simple activity for Android 15 and see that a part of top TextView is hiden.
I guess this is a bug of edge-to-edge mode.
How to disable this mode or fix this problem?
I tryed many ways to show system bar but it always invisible.


This is not a bug, it appears that you are still using Material 2 components you have to handle the insets yourself.
You can temporarily add to your app theme
<item name="android:windowOptOutEdgeToEdgeEnforcement">true</item>

but this will be deprecated/removed in future versions and you will have to handle it anyway. I suggest you look at the code lab on how to handle edge to edge
Updating to Material 3 components will help since components are made to handle edge to edge without the manual work

You can use below line in the parent view of your activity and it should work.
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
This will basically add insets to your view
